# why cloud code is stored in my computer

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

My iOS app is deployed to Heroku using Parse SDK. Why is the cloud code stored on my local computer and not in the server side (cloud code such as index.js & main.js)?

What is the relationship between my computer and the Heroku server?

Answer (score 0):

The code on your computer is a copy of what is stored in the cloud. It is there solely for you to edit.

When you do the command `parse deploy`, you push your changes to the server. This overwrites the copy hosted on the server with the code on your machine.

The copy that is hosted in the server is the code that your app communicates with.